# How to mixin traits declared in wrapper trait's self-types in an embedded type?

Tags: scala

I was wondering if it is possible to mixin self types from a wrapper trait

For instance:

```scala
trait PolicyHolderDAOComponent { this: DbConfig with ActorSystemConfig =>

  //want to use the injected DbConfig and ActorSystemConfig for instantiation of policyHolderDAO 
  def policyHolderDAO = new PolicyHolderDAO 
  class PolicyHolderDAO { this: DbConfig with ActorSystemConfig => 
    ... 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give `this` a different name, then you can refer to it from the inner class:

```
trait PolicyHolderDAOComponent { self: DbConfig with ActorSystemConfig =>
  def policyHolderDAO = new PolicyHolderDAO

  class PolicyHolderDAO { this: DbConfig with ActorSystemConfig =>
    // use self
  }
}
```

Note that `self` is both of type `DbConfig` and `ActorSystemConfig`.

Comment: This is not what I am trying to do. I want to mixin the self-types from `PolicyHolderDAOComponent` into the instantiation of `PolicyHolderDAO`

Comment: Then just do `new PolicyHolderDAO with DbConfig with ActorSystemConfig`? I don't see the problem.

Comment: Assume `DbConfig` is a abstract trait. You could have `DbConfigTest`, or `DbConfigProduction` etc. Will mixing in `DbConfig` be the exact same instance of that you passed into `PolicyDAOComponent`? I am under the impression that it will not be.

Comment: No, you cannot mixin instances, only traits.